# Update Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I use Python 3 and I'm quite new to programming. I have written a code that's supposed to show a window in which you can move around two planets and see the gravitational force between them. 
Everything works excepted the label that's supposed to display the force. After multiple attempts and searches, I just can't find out how to update it every time a planet is being moved.

I guess my problem should be in the last line with :

```
lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white', text = gravitation(oval1, oval2)).pack(padx=5, pady=5)
```

I've tried to use a StringVar and a textvariable parameter but I didn't really get the concepts of it.

Here is my code. I guess the answer is easy but I'm quite unexperienced.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

x, y = 135, 135
gravitation = 0

def gravitation (obj1,obj2):
    a, b, c, d = can.coords (obj1)
    e, f, g, h = can.coords (obj2)
    dist = math.sqrt ((((a+c)/2)-((e+g)/2))**2+(((b+d)/2)-((f+h)/2))**2)
    grav = 6.67384/dist
    return grav

def move (ov, lr, tb): # function to move the ball
    coo = can.coords(ov)
    coo[0] = coo[0] + lr
    coo[1] = coo[1] + tb
    coo[2] = coo[0]+30
    coo[3] = coo[1]+30
    can.coords(ov, *coo)


def moveLeft ():
    move(oval1, -10, 0)

def moveRight ():
    move(oval1, 10, 0)

def moveTop ():
    move(oval1, 0, -10)

def moveBottom ():
    move(oval1, 0, 10)

def moveLeft2 ():
    move(oval2, -10, 0)

def moveRight2 ():
    move(oval2, 10, 0)

def moveTop2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, -10)

def moveBottom2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, 10)


##########MAIN############

wind = Tk() # Window and canvas
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")
can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.pack (side = LEFT,padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval1 = can.create_oval(x,y,x+30,y+30,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 1 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval2 = can.create_oval(x+50,y+50,x+80,y+80,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 2 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white', text = gravitation(oval1, oval2)).pack(padx=5, pady=5)

wind.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there is a few things that need to be done.  First, make your label like this:

```
lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white', text = gravitation(oval1, oval2))
lbl.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
# Put this on its own line so that there are no errors since 'lbl' isn't defined yet
gravitation(oval1, oval2)
```

This will make `lbl` refer to the label like it should, not `pack`, which returns `None`.

Second, you will need to put this:

```
gravitation(oval1, oval2)
```

at the end of your `move` function so that, each time a movement in any direction takes place, it will update the label.

Third, instead of returning `grav` in `gravitation`, put this at the end:

```
lbl["text"] = grav
```

Now, each time `gravitation` is called, the label will be updated.

All in all, this should do what you want:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

x, y = 135, 135

def gravitation (obj1,obj2):
    a, b, c, d = can.coords (obj1)
    e, f, g, h = can.coords (obj2)
    dist = math.sqrt ((((a+c)/2)-((e+g)/2))**2+(((b+d)/2)-((f+h)/2))**2)
    grav = 6.67384/dist
    ##################
    lbl["text"] = grav
    ##################

def move (ov, lr, tb):
    coo = can.coords(ov)
    coo[0] = coo[0] + lr
    coo[1] = coo[1] + tb
    coo[2] = coo[0]+30
    coo[3] = coo[1]+30
    can.coords(ov, *coo)
    ########################
    gravitation(oval1, oval2)
    ########################


def moveLeft ():
    move(oval1, -10, 0)

def moveRight ():
    move(oval1, 10, 0)


def moveTop ():
    move(oval1, 0, -10)

def moveBottom ():
    move(oval1, 0, 10)

def moveLeft2 ():
    move(oval2, -10, 0)

def moveRight2 ():
    move(oval2, 10, 0)

def moveTop2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, -10)

def moveBottom2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, 10)



wind = Tk()
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")
can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.pack (side = LEFT,padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval1 = can.create_oval(x,y,x+30,y+30,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 1 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval2 = can.create_oval(x+50,y+50,x+80,y+80,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 2 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

###############################
lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white')
lbl.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
gravitation(oval1, oval2)
##############################

wind.mainloop()
```

I put comment boxes around everything I changed.  Also, I removed `gravitation = 0` at the start since defining the `gravitation` function will overwrite this.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help. Actually I was hoping there is another way than this one to do it, but this one works. I'll just wait a bit more to see if someone has an idea, otherwise I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Pierreocinom: What don't you like about this solution?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in programing so I might not have the knowledge to say what I don't like about a solution, as I don't have any clue myself. But if I should mention it, it's the fact that I need to call the gravitation function in every move function. I'd prefer keeping my code more universal, if I can say so. I'm just working on something else, an it almost works, excepted a small problem. I'm just writing a new question, you might have a look.

Comment: @PierreOcinom - I just thought of something (don't know why I didn't earlier).  After reading your above comment, I began thinking of a way to get the job done without calling `gravitation` in each move function.  My solution is to put the call to `gravitation` IN the `move` function.  See my edit.  This eliminates the need of calling `gravitation` all those times.

Comment: Hahaha. Indeed, this is so easy even I should have seen it. Thanks a lot.