# Tkinter Label not updating correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I've already asked a question this afternoon about how to update a label in Tkinter an got an answer that worked. 
However, I found the "solution" code a bit long and tried to improve it. 
Basically I'm using an `updt` function that executes a configure `method` on the label `lbl`. The method will change the label text by calling the `gravitation` function. 
I used the bind method on the whole window to call the `updt` function every time I click somewhere.

The problem is now that the program won't work correctly, as the number displayed in the label isn't correct and doesn't always show the same value eventhough the planets are at the same distance as before.

I read every line carefully, but as I'm quite new to programming I couldn't find what's wrong.

I'm using Python 3.

Here is my previous code : [Update Tkinter Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576978/update-tkinter-label)

This is the new one :

```
from tkinter import *
import math

x, y = 135, 135

def gravitation (obj1,obj2):
    a, b, c, d = can.coords (obj1)
    e, f, g, h = can.coords (obj2)
    dist = math.sqrt ((((a+c)/2)-((e+g)/2))**2+(((b+d)/2)-((f+h)/2))**2)
    if dist != 0:
        grav = 6.67384/dist
    else:
        grav = "Infinite"
    str(grav)
    return grav

def updt (event):
    lbl.configure (text = gravitation(oval1, oval2)) 

def move (ov, lr, tb): # function to move the ball
    coo = can.coords(ov)
    coo[0] = coo[0] + lr
    coo[1] = coo[1] + tb
    coo[2] = coo[0]+30
    coo[3] = coo[1]+30
    can.coords(ov, *coo)


def moveLeft ():
    move(oval1, -10, 0)


def moveRight ():
    move(oval1, 10, 0)


def moveTop ():
    move(oval1, 0, -10)


def moveBottom ():
    move(oval1, 0, 10)


def moveLeft2 ():
    move(oval2, -10, 0)


def moveRight2 ():
    move(oval2, 10, 0)


def moveTop2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, -10)


def moveBottom2 ():
    move(oval2, 0, 10)



##########MAIN############

wind = Tk() # Window and canvas
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")
can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5, rowspan =4)
Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
wind.bind ("<Button-1>", updt)


oval1 = can.create_oval(x,y,x+30,y+30,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 1 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)



oval2 = can.create_oval(x+50,y+50,x+80,y+80,width=2,fill='blue') #Planet 2 moving etc
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=moveLeft2).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=moveRight2).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=moveTop2).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=moveBottom2).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)




lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white')#label
lbl.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan = 3)
gravitation (oval1, oval2)


wind.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updt` triggers when the user clicks down on any part of your window, and the move functions trigger when the user clicks on the button, and then releases it. As a result, `updt` is always called before the move function is. So the label reports the gravitational force of the planets on one another *before* they move to their new positions.

Instead of binding `updt` to a global click event, put it in the `move` function, after the coordinates change.

```
def updt():
    lbl.configure (text = gravitation(oval1, oval2)) 

def move (ov, lr, tb): # function to move the ball
    coo = can.coords(ov)
    coo[0] = coo[0] + lr
    coo[1] = coo[1] + tb
    coo[2] = coo[0]+30
    coo[3] = coo[1]+30
    can.coords(ov, *coo)
    updt()
```

Comment: Yeah, actually that's the way of doing it, as we also found out in the post I've linked. In this case the only difference is that we use a method where in the other one we use 'lbl["text"] = grav'.
But your explanation is very helpful, as I get why it doesn't work that way. Thank you.